# pre html - &nbsp; M-BM- bash scripts syntax highlighting on the web - remove ASCII representation of byte sequence 0xc2 0xa0

Tags: javascript, html, bash, pre

If you copy the bash script (contained in a `<pre>` element and highlighted using the SyntaxHighlighter plugin http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)  from https://hoodlogic.tk/pre_bash_nbsp.html and save it in a file called test.sh, when you try to run the test.sh bash script (in Linux tested on Ubuntu 16.04), you get the following syntax errors:

```
bash -n test.sh
test.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
test.sh: line 2: `    if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then'
```

If you use the `cat -A` command on the script, you'll see lots of this in the output:

```
cat -A test.sh
M-BM-M-BM-M-BM-M-BM-M-BM-M-BM-M-BM-M-BM-M-BM-M-BM-
```

You can remove these using `sed` (referenced here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/357248/how-to-remove-special-m-bm-character-with-sed), but my question is how do I copy the script client side from the browser and have it so that the `&nbsp;` characters are converted to the Linux space character?

Anyone know?  Copying the text out of the `<code>` blocks using this jQuery snippet doesn't remove the M-BM characters either when pasted into a `<textarea>` in the browser.

```
var textToCopy = "";
var i = 0;
$(".code .container .line", elem.parent()).each(function(e){
    if(i == 0){
        textToCopy += $(this).text();
    }else{
        textToCopy += "\n" + $(this).text();
    }
    i++;
});
$("textarea").val(textToCopy);
```

This appears to have nothing to do with line endings.  If you download the raw batch file manually, the script works as it should, as there are no non-breaking spaces in the source, but if you load it into the `<pre>` for SyntaxHighlighting using PHP's `echo file_get_contents("file");` command, `&nbsp;` are now added to your script.

Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a combination of things (including different browser behavior):

The syntax highlighter script should not be using `&nbsp;` entries in the code sections since it already uses the following CSS style `white-space: pre;`.  Thus, it should look like this:

```
<style>
.spaces { white-space: pre; }
</style>

<code class="bash spaces">    </code>
```

But the syntax highlighter script produces this:

```
<code class="bash spaces">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</code>
```

That causes Chrome to copy the text with `&nbsp;`.  Firefox won't though because of this:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359303

So, because the syntax highlighter script does it wrong, you have to convert the `&nbsp;` characters to normal spaces before the text gets copied:

```
textToCopy.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(160), "g"), " ");
```

Unfortunately, it's very complicated, and I wish that Chrome behaved like Firefox in this case and automatically converted `&nbsp;` characters to an actual space for Linux and Windows.  But since it doesn't, I have to handle it differently.